# Emulate sequence on MySql with Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

I would need to emulate a sequence on MySql.

As explained in this answer [Emulating a transaction-safe SEQUENCE in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805808/emulating-a-transaction-safe-sequence-in-mysql)

I need to run two queries in the same session.

```
UPDATE sequence SET seq_current = (@next := seq_current + 1) WHERE seq_name = 'foo';
SELECT @next;
```

How can I do it with Eloquent?

Comment: You can only run these as raw sql queries and will essentially be outside of any object model.

Comment: Do not use this method - it is not safe in concurrent environ. Use trigger technique with additional table. PS. XY-problem. You must post the task, not your attempt to solve it only.